# Column Data Type - mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point, sqldatatypes

This is part of my query

`(t.as_num_responded-sqrt(t.as_num_responded))/t.as_num_subjects as 'RF score'`

where t is my database, the problem arrives when I try to use the `coalesce` function, it doesn't work on it, to replace the `NULL` to 0.

`coalesce(t.as_num_responded-sqrt(t.as_num_responded))/t.as_num_subjects) as 'RF score'`

Not sure if I'm using the `coalesce` wrong or if it is because the new column 'RF score' is created as a `varchar`, I need the values as floats with two decimals. Please, any help will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Coalesce goes through a list of values until it finds a non null value to bring back.  Giving it only one field means it's finding this one to be null, then going to the next field (there isn't one) so it returns null.   isnull(yourfunction,0) might be an easier way of handling this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment is pretty much an answer I guess.

Coalesce goes through a list of values and returns the first non-null value in doing so.  Unfortunately you are giving it one arguement, and if that value is null...it goes to the next, finds nothing, and returns null.

2 ways of fixing...

```
coalesce (yourfunction,0)
```

where yourfunction is the (t.as_num_responded-sqrt(t.as_num_responded))/t.as_num_subjects) line

This will return 0 when your function is null.

```
Isnull(yourfunction,0)
```

Isnull is a more simple version...instead of taking a list of fields, it just does one field and replaces nulls with the second arguement of the isnull function.